# Unity3D IP Camera

Tags: unity-game-engine, ip-camera

I'm using a Marmitek IP RoboCam 641 to import a video feed into unity. I use constantly refreshing snapshots to update a GUI.DrawTexture on the screen. However I recently switched to the Marmitek from a Velleman wireless ip colour camera. Now my snapshot only refreshes once or twice, before stopping and giving this error:

UnityException: Recv failure: Connection was reset
SEMTEX+c__Iterator0.MoveNext () (at Assets/Scripts/SEMTEX.cs:37)

And this is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SEMTEX : MonoBehaviour {

//public string uri = "http://192.168.1.101/snapshot.cgi";//velleman
public string uri = "http://192.168.1.30/cgi/jpg/image.cgi";//marmitek
public string username = "admin";
public string password = "admin";
int calc = 0;


Texture2D cam;
Texture2D cam2;


public void Start() {
    cam=new Texture2D(1, 1, TextureFormat.RGB24, true);
    StartCoroutine(Fetch());
    cam2=new Texture2D(1, 1, TextureFormat.RGB24, true);
    StartCoroutine(Fetch());
}


public IEnumerator Fetch() {
    while(true) {
        Debug.Log("fetching... "+Time.realtimeSinceStartup);

        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField("dummy", "field");    // required by WWWForm
        WWW www = new WWW(uri, form.data, new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,string>() {  // using www.headers is depreciated by some odd reason
            {"Authorization", "Basic " + System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(username+":"+password))}
        });
        yield return www;

        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))
            throw new UnityException(www.error);

        www.LoadImageIntoTexture(cam);
        www.LoadImageIntoTexture(cam2);
    }
}


public void OnGUI() {
    GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(0,0,Screen.width/2,Screen.height), cam);

    calc = (Screen.width/2-100);

    GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(calc,0,Screen.width/2,Screen.height), cam2);
    Debug.Log (Screen.width);
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas regarding my error?

Comment: Oh, my bad. Here it is: UnityException: Recv failure: Connection was reset
SEMTEX+<Fetch>c__Iterator0.MoveNext () (at Assets/Scripts/SEMTEX.cs:37)

Comment: Have you tried hitting the camera through some other means? "Connection was reset" implies to me that the camera is dropping the connection, not that there's anything wrong with your code.

Comment: I can view through the camera using the program the company provided, that works fine. But I need to replicate the effect for a project, in Unity3D. And somehow after display a few frames, it stops geting new snapshots.